# redirect doesn't convert special characters correctly on redirect in django

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a page in my django app that requires authentication. If the user hits `mydomian/my_page` the view will evaluate if the request is authenticated. If authenticated the request will get routed to the right html page (`my_page.html`). If the request is unauthenticated the request will be routed to the login page with a redirect:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        context = {
            'username': user.username
        }

        if user.is_authenticated and user.is_staff:
            return render(request,
                          'path/to/my_page.html',
                          context)
        logout(request)

        return redirect('/admin/login?next=/my_page')
```

This worked pretty well, when an unauthenticated user hit `mydomain/my_page` it will get routed to `mydomain/admin/login/?next=/my_page` and once authenticated it will get routed to `mydomain/my_page` with will serve `path/to/my_page.html`.

Now I updated to the latest django version and the rerouting changed: When an unauthenticated request hits my page it gets rerouted to this url `mydomain/admin/login/?next=/admin/login%3Fnext%3D/my_path`. Once the login happens on that page, the page gets rerouted to `mydomain/admin` instead of `mydomain/my_page`. Then when I call `mydomain/my_page` it gets routed to the right page (since the request is authenticated).

I tried replacing the redirect with

```
return HttpResponseRedirect((('/admin/login?next=/my_page').encode('utf-8')))
```

but didn't work. I also couldn't find anything in the django docs on if and how the changed the redirect method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upond reviewing the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-raw-way) and [here](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-url) I figured the redirect now wants a slash after admin.

so this `return redirect('/admin/login/?next=/my_page')` solved my problem. Otherwise it's appending the provided link to my url.